# Stripe: How to retrieve transfer information from a connected account

Tags: php, stripe-payments

My main account is in GBP and I have a connected account in EURO. My main account gets paid into first and then a percentage is transferred to the EURO.

If a customer pays in EURO, it goes into my GBP account at a fee and exchange rate. Commission is calculated and that gets transferred in to EURO account.

I can see in EURO->GBP exchange and in EURO account I can see GBP->EURO exchange.

I can retrieve all the details from each accounts transfer process, except that last exchange back into EURO on the connected account.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
// To retrieve data from main GBP account
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve($charge_id);
$transfer = \Stripe\Transfer::retrieve($transfer_id);                                                           
$balance = \Stripe\BalanceTransaction::retrieve($charge['balance_transaction']);

// To retrieve data from EURO connected account
$transfer_eur= \Stripe\Transfer::retrieve($transfer_id,[                                                                             
    'account' => $eur_acc_number                                                                         
]);                                                                      
$balance_eur= \Stripe\BalanceTransaction::retrieve($transfer_eur['balance_transaction'],[                                                                            
    'account' => $eur_acc_number                                                                     
]);
```

This is my results:

```
$charge['amount'] // shows customer EUR amount
$balance['amount'] // shows the convert customers amount in GBP

$transfer_eur['amount'] // shows the GBP amount in the connect EUR account
$balance_eur['amount'] // just show the a negative GBP value of the EUR account
```

I expected the the `$balance_eur['amount']` to show me the EUR value but it just shows me a negative GBP value.

I'm just about there but I just can't get the EURO value from the connected account. Is it possible?

**[EDITED]**

Something I tried, but failed on was to use the `destination_payment` by somehow using the `payment ID - py_****`

```
$balance_other = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve($charge_id,[                                                                       
    'account' => $row['stripe_acc'],
    'destination_payment' => $payment_id                                                                         
]);
```

Comment: Hi, when platform does a `transfer` to a connected account. It will create a `Balance Transaction` object and `Transfer` object in platform account. However, in the connected account, it will create a corresponding `payment` object and transaction object. 
To get the dollar amount in connected account, you would have to use the attribute here https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/object?lang=dotnet#transfer_object-destination_payment and get the payment details out by calling the charge api

Comment: I thought of that but not sure how to call the payment details using `destination_payment`

Comment: @wsw please see '[EDITED]' to see what I try, but can't get working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want to take the transfer, get the `destination_payment` of that to look at the payment that arrived on the connected account, and then get the `balance_transaction` associated with that payment on the connected account. It will also help to use the API's [expanding objects](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) feature for this.

```
$t = \Stripe\Transfer::create([
  "amount" => 400,
  "currency" => "eur",
  "destination" => "acct_1EPRDuFk3qO2dNo1"
]);
$transfer_id = $t->id;
$transfer_eur= \Stripe\Transfer::retrieve([
  'id' => $transfer_id,
  'expand' => ['destination_payment.balance_transaction']
]);
$balance_transaction_eu = $transfer_eur->destination_payment->balance_transaction;
print_r($balance_transaction_eu);
```

You could also simplify this a lot by getting the relevant data at the time you make the transfer too :

```
$t = \Stripe\Transfer::create([
  "amount" => 400,
  "currency" => "eur",
  "destination" => "acct_1EPRDuFk3qO2dNo1",
  'expand' => ['destination_payment.balance_transaction']
]);
$balance_transaction_eu = $t->destination_payment->balance_transaction;
print_r($balance_transaction_eu);
```